# App (Distribuida) se cierra al Consultar Base de datos

Tags: xamarin.android, apk

estoy iniciando en la programación de Apps y tengo un error que no se como solucionarlo, lo describo:

En la app que estoy desarrollando le hice un inicio de sesión y un registro, **todo funciona perfecto**, puedo registrarme y logear (sql server) , lo probé en un emulador y en un celular android.

Luego la compilé en Release y luego la Distribuí, el archivo lo descargué en mi celular android, desinstalé la aplicación que se instala con el visual studio y descargue el APK distribuida, la instalé, abrí la app y **al momento de ingresar el usuario y contraseña o al momento de realizar un registro se cierra**, no se cómo obtener el error.

```
public static string ValidarIngreso(string Usuario, string Contraseña)
    {
        Datos.clsConexion.Abrir();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Usuario FROM tbl_estudiantes WHERE Usuario='" + Usuario + "' AND Contraseña='"+Contraseña+"'" , clsConexion.conectar);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string a;
        if (rdr.Read() is true)
        {
            a = "Welcome";
        }
        else
        {
            a = "None";
        }
        Datos.clsConexion.Cerrar();
        return a;
    }

private async void btnIngresar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Traer de la bd la contraseña del usuario.
        if (Datos.D_estudiantes.ValidarIngreso(txtNombre.Text, txtContraseña.Text) == "Welcome")
        {
            //Ingresar nombre pasando variable
            
            await ((NavigationPage)this.Parent).PushAsync(new Presentacion.EnviarFoto());
        }
        else
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Advertencia", "Usuario o contraseña incorrectas", "Aceptar");
        }
                               
    }
```

Me funciona bien, pero en el APK que genero e instalo en un celular se cierra la aplicación.

Primeramente creo el archivo de la conexión.

```
private void crear_archivo()
    {
        ruta = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "connection.txt");
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ruta);
        StreamWriter sw;
        try
        {
            string parte1 = "Data source =";
            string parte2 = "; Initial Catalog = *******; Integrated Security=False; User Id=*****; Password=*******";

            if (File.Exists(ruta) == false)
            {
                sw = File.CreateText(ruta);
                sw.WriteLine(parte1 + txtconexion.Text + parte2);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
            else if (File.Exists(ruta) == true)
            {
                File.Delete(ruta);
                sw = File.CreateText(ruta);

                sw.WriteLine(parte1 + txtconexion.Text + parte2);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }

    }
```

Conexión, paso el archivo creado anteriormente

```
class clsConexion
{
    public static string ruta= System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "connection.txt");
    public static string text = File.ReadAllText(ruta);
    public static SqlConnection conectar = new SqlConnection(text);

    public static void Abrir()
    {
        if (conectar.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conectar.Open();
        }
    }
    public static void Cerrar()
    {
        if (conectar.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conectar.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código del inicio de sesión? Hiciste las pruebas conectando a tu máquina o a un servidor?

Comment: Hola, si realicé las pruebas, ejecute la aplicación en un celular android, este celular estaba conectado a mis datos móviles, la aplicación pide mi IP pública de mi router, la coloqué y ingresé con normalidad, puedo crear usuarios con normalidad, el detalle es cuando creo el Distribuíble, instalo la aplicación cuando le doy a ingresar con usuario y contraseña se detiene.

Comment: Parece que hiciste las pruebas en tu máquina local y no en un servidor al que se pueda acceder de cualquier sitio.

Comment: Mi SqlServer esta configurado para que se pueda acceder desde internet con los puertos configurados y el router también, puedo hacer consultas desde una página web.

Comment: Cuál es el código de la conexión? Puedes cambiar la información sensible por asteriscos.

Comment: Allí la adjunté.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo.
En modo Debug funcionaba todo bien.
En modo Release no accedía a la base de datos, lo que me faltaba era agregar en las propiedades del proyecto - Opciones de Android - Codificaciones Admitidas adicionales - West.

Gracias.